# SEO plugin for Sitecore

Tags: experience-editor, content-editor, content-management, seo

I am looking for recommendations of SEO plugins for Sitecore 10. I am aware of [Sitecore SEO Toolkit](https://doc.sitecore.com/en/SdnArchive/Products/Seo%20Toolkit.html), but as far as I know it doesn't support Sitecore 8+.

Our content editors come from WordPress background and are looking for similar capabilities that Yoast or SemRush provided them in WP.

Do you have any suggestions for plugins or strategies that enables content editors deal with SEO in an easy way?

Comment: Are you building a SXA site? You get quite a bit in that OOTB and you can then add any additional bits and pieces you might need quite easily

Comment: @DaveGoosem, no we are not using SXA. It's classic MVC implementation.

Comment: Looks like @John King has some options below which are good ones :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend using the Siteimprove and the Sitecore connector. Siteimprove is a brilliant tool for doing SEO and performance audits. https://siteimprove.com/en/core-platform/integrations/cms-plugin/sitecore/

There is another SEO plugin that I have seen used in the Sitecore community is called Avtor. https://www.teamdevelopmentforsitecore.com/Avtor/Sitecore-Seo

Comment: Thanks @John King!